# How to get the id in form submit for custom Autocomplete react material component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to get this to work, but keep getting weird behavior. Basically I want to have a custom Autocomplete component like so:

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material"

const animalOptions = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Bear' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Wolf' },
    { id: 4, label: 'Cat' },
    { id: 5, label: 'Dog' },
    { id: 6, label: 'Bird' },
    { id: 7, label: 'Elephant' },
];

export const AnimalSelect = ({ id }) => {

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id={id}
            options={animalOptions}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} />}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
        />
    );
}
```

This will be used in a form:

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { AnimalSelect } from "./AnimalSelect";

export const Sandbox = props => {

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { animals } = e.target.elements;
        console.log("selected animal = ", animals.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Sandbox</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <AnimalSelect id="animals" />
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The goal is that in the `handleSubmit()` function, I want to be able to get the animal `id` instead of the animal name. How do I modify the AnimalSelect component to make it do that instead of returning the animal name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely choose the "controlled" approach to get the `id` of the currently selected value. The "HTMLish" approach is IMO not the way to go in React.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-rgb-fzvd94?file=/Demo.tsx

```
export const AnimalSelect = ({ id, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      onChange={onChange}
      id={id}
      options={animalOptions}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
    />
  );
};

const Sandbox = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (evt, value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit", "id: ", value.id, "name: ", value.label);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sandbox</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <AnimalSelect id="animals" onChange={handleChange} />
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```